# Create three divs such that the top and bottom ones have fixed height, and the middle one has dynamic height?

Tags: html, css

I want to create three, stacked `div`s. The top and the bottom ones will be of fixed height, whereas the one in the middle will have a dynamic height that expands to fill the remaining space:

[image]

I've tried numerous things, such as setting the height to `auto`. I do have a solution, but it involves JavaScript (i.e., calculating the remaining height) but I was wondering if there was a pure CSS solution.

Comment: have you tried percentages?

Comment: @sircapsalot Yes, I did but I would like the top and bottom divs to have an actual, fixed height and not a width that is a percentage of the viewport height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a CSS solution, but it won't work in older browsers. You need to use the `calc` "function" that is new to CSS, combined with `height: 100%`. If you've never used `height: 100%` before, you know that every parent element of the one you want to be 100% tall must also be set to `height:100%`. `calc` can take a percentage value and subtract pixels from it, so you just need to set it to be `100%` minus however tall the top and bottom divs are.

Supported by: IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome 19+, Safari 6+
http://caniuse.com/calc

**HTML**

```
<div id='top'></div>
<div id='mid'></div>
<div id='bot'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

#top, #bot
{
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
}

#mid
{
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/9cYUB/

Comment: What does support for `calc` look like? Is it available for all "new" browsers (i.e., latest versions of Chrome, FF, etc.) Older browsers may not be an issue. I'm using some advanced features as it is (and it is aimed towards browsers that support those kinds of features).

Comment: It's IE9+ according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly for my needs and seems to be supported in most mobile browsers also. Thank you!

Comment: Using fixed heights when text is involved is a recipe for disaster.  Most mobile devices do *not* support `calc()`.

Comment: Most recent mobile devices DO support it, and will going forward. The ONLY major browser that it doesn't work on is Android Browser, which is no longer the default browser on new versions of Android.

Comment: And as far as fixed heights go, the OP specifically said he was using them.

Comment: @Jake The reality is that old mobile devices stick around *forever*.  According to Google, ~40% of Androids are running version 3.2 when current version is 4.2.  Upgrading is not an option for many users, as using the "upgrade" option frequently reports that they're "using the latest version" unless they take the time to unlock it.  Don't overlook Opera for mobile just because the desktop version is unpopular (it's found on many feature phones).

Comment: @Jake I don't have representative numbers, but at least the branded Galaxy S4 I have seen had _Android Browser_ as their default.

Comment: Even though it might not be an ideal solution, the truth is that it's the only way to do this in pure CSS without wrestling with it. The OP said he already had a JS method, but was wondering if there was a CSS method. I gave him the only one. The only other options are to fake the browser into table mode, or use absolute positioning, and both of those are prone to bugs.

Comment: I do not have a lot of text; what I do have is static (one word). The top is pretty much a header and the bottom is a sort of "control panel". The middle section will contain text, but it is a PDF that has been rendered using pdf.js and pdf.js can render to a canvas that is of fixed height and width. So this works pretty well for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to do it with position `absolute`.

The downside of this approach is that if the total height of surrounding is smaller then the sum of the fixed heights the `container` will not be visible anymore.

Another thing to be noted is that this is probably a bad solution if you want to target mobile devices. It always depends on the exact situation if this solution is suitable.

If i remember right you will only have problems with IE 6 (on desktop) which does not support the `top` `bottom` combination for the position `absolute`.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="container"></div>
 <div class="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .header, .container, .footer{
      position: absolute;
      outline: 1px solid black;
  }

  .header {
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      right : 0px;
      height: 50px;
  }


  .container {
      left: 0px;
      top: 50px;
      right : 0px;
      bottom: 50px;
  }


  .footer {
      left: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      right : 0px;
      height: 50px;
  }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WwSNV/)

Comment: I do want to target mobile devices, in fact this is a view that I'm trying to create *for* mobile devices. But thanks anyway, this is still a solution I can use in other places!

Comment: @VivinPaliath I never tried if that approach works reliable on mobile devices. The problem I had with this is when i did want to apply scrolling to the `container`, because on older iOS devices (and probably also on other mobile browsers) the one finger scrolling only worked on the _window_ itself, and for the others html elements with _overflow_ the _two finger scrolling_ had to be done, which was a not acceptable break in usability.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a HTML table if you need older browser support, or if you need to support [IE8+ or higher you could use the CSS table layout](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZuMU/3/)</kbd> using CSS table layout.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>Fixed Height</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>Variable Height</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Fixed Height</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20pt;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
body > div {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
body > div > div {
    display: table-row;
}
body > div > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(even) {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(even) >div {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you request you need to use wrap div: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html

Comment: I'm not trying to make a sticky footer. I'm trying to expand a middle div to the available viewport height after the top and bottom divs have been assigned a fixed height.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do

Comment: That's what a sticky footer *is*.  The footer rests at the bottom of the page, regardless of how tall the page is.  (Also, this answer is very low quality.  How useful will it be when cssstickyfooter.com goes away?)